# What is the difference between the following two uses of `putchar`?

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, getchar, putchar

I was writing some code where I was getting an unexpected output in one part of the program, which in turn disrupted the entire system.

The code can be simplified and shortened to:

```
char ch;
printf("Enter Number: ");

while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
   if (ch >= 65 && ch <= 67)  {
         ch = 2;
   }
   putchar(ch);
}
```

As per the code above, I am trying to print a character/integer sequence of the user's choice. The numbers should remain unchanged whereas if the user enters letter `A`, then this should print `2`.

*Expected Output*

```
Enter Number: 23-AB
23-22
```

*Actual Output*

```
Enter Number: 23-AB
23-☺☺
```

Once confronted with this problem, I decided to tweak some things and came up with the following code which worked perfectly.  It uses the same approach but produces different output:

```
char input;
printf("\nEnter Number: ");

while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {  

    switch (toupper(ch)) {   //toupper function not really needed since I am expecting the user to enter upper-case letters ONLY
    case 'A': case 'B': case 'C':
        printf("2");
        break;
    default:
        putchar(ch);
    }
}
```

*Expected Output*

```
Enter Number: 23-AB
23-22
```

*Actual Output*

```
Enter Number: 23-AB
23-22
```

I am unable to comprehend why I am failing to convert the ASCII value of the characters entered in the first code to a single integer.  What is the reason for this difference in the outputs?  I have simply changed the type of controlling expression, from `if-statement` to a `switch-statement` (or so I think). How can I alter the first code to provide me with the same output as the second code?

Comment: `ch = 2;` --> `ch = '2';`, and the result of `getchar()` is an `int` (not a `char`)

Comment: Don't use _magic numbers_! Is `'A'` instead of `65` etc. too clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first version, setting `ch=2;` makes `ch` the character with ASCII value 2, not the character `2`.  `ch=0x32;` in your first version would probably work, since ASCII 50 = 0x32 is character `2`.  Even easier (and better, as Weather Vane points out) is `ch='2';`.

In your second version, you are using `printf("2")`.  As a result, the compiler is producing the ASCII value for you when it processes the string `"2"`, just as it would for `ch='2';`.  Try `printf("%d\n",'2');` and you should see `50`.

Comment: Please do not use magic numbers which assume how characters are encoded. Keine Lust who you originally quoted used `'2'` not `0x32`.